# Excel add- in focus not returned to the active sheet

Tags: excel, focus, add-in, cell

I have developed an excel add-in (VSTO) in c# and that has a task pane with tree view in it. When I click the tree view it loads some data to excel sheet. But after loading the focus still remains on the tree view so that i cant directly type on in the cell without clicking on the sheet. I need to take the focus to active work sheet as soon as the sheet is populate upon the click of the tree view. I tried following methods but no luck

```
ActiveSheet.Select()
ActiveSheet.Activate()
```

And i tried setting the range as well.
One other thing is that when I add a break point to the `ActiveSheet.Activate()` it works after hitting the break point but without that it still keeps the focus on the task pane.

Answer (score 4):

After trying hard I found a simple solution

SendKeys.Send("{F1}");

This simply solved my problem. But yet strange because actually F2 is the proper key but it doesn't work. Only F1 works.

Comment: +1 und thank you for this hint. I had the same problem. I think some windows forms controls keep the keyboard focus in some way, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

The SendKeys.Send("{F1}") approach didn't work for me. I think that what is happening is that we are trying to activate a window that thinks it is already activated, except that it's not fully activated.

So, we need to activate another window to ensure that Excel gets properly deactivated, then reactivate Excel. But, we don't want the user to see any flickering or weirdness. The approach that worked for me was to:

1. Get the handle of the desktop
2. Call SetForegroundWindow on the desktop handle
3. Call SetForegroundWindow on the main Excel handle

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetDesktopWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

```
SetForegroundWindow(GetDesktopWindow());
SetForegroundWindow(excelHandle);
```

Comment: I think the declaration of GetDesktopWindow() should be:
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

Comment: If you don't already have an `excelHandle` variable laying around you need to use   `new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd)` for it.

Where do people even learn about this DllImport magic?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using Add-in Express to create an Excel add-in, you can use `ADXKeyFilter` event and set the `Action` property of the default handler arguments to `ADXKeyFilterAction.SendToHostApplication`.